# Swift newbie question: How to make an Alignment hashable?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to use an Alignment in a Picker:

`@State private var favouriteCorner: Alignment`

`...`

`Picker("Select favourite corner", selection: $favouriteCorner)`

But I get a compiler error: Generic struct 'Picker' requires that 'Alignment' conform to 'Hashable'

So, how do I make Alignment hashable?

The "old" way seems to be to implement '==' operator (and some other stuff), but now it's by implementing "func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)". But I can't find any explanations on how to do this that I can apply to Alignment, so I would appreciate some guidance here.

I haven't been able to write any code at all that will compile.

Comment: Create an enum that is hashable and maps to Alignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Alignment` is not designed to be `Hashable`. A possible reason is that alignments can be created from custom `AlignmentID` types (see the example in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/alignmentid)), and these metatypes are not `Hashable`.

For a `Picker` that picks an alignment, I would write an enum for the available choices:

```
enum AlignmentChoice {
    case top, leading, center, trailing, bottom
    
    // convenient property for getting a SwiftUI Alignment from an enum case
    var alignment: Alignment {
        switch self {
        case .top:
            .top
        case .leading:
            .leading
        case .center:
            .center
        case .trailing:
            .trailing
        case .bottom:
            .bottom
        }
    }
}
```

```
@State var choice = AlignmentChoice.center
var body: some View {
    Picker("Alignment", selection: $choice) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I would not recommend this, but it is *technically* possible to conform `Alignment` to `Hashable`, vacuously. It is technically valid to just do nothing in `hash(into:)`

```
extension Alignment: Hashable {
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        
    }
}
```

Every `Alignment` would have the same hash code.

Comment: Thank you! This works great for the Picker problem. I replaced all my Alignment variables with AlignmentChoice, and in places where an Alignment is expected, as in "ZStack(alignment:...", I use "alignmentChoiceVariable.alignment". This compiles, and runs in the simulator. But my previews no longer works. I get a timeout: "Updating took more than 5 seconds". My initial thought was if the solution somehow creates a loop, but then the code wouldn't work in the simulator, so that's probably not the issue. Are there any other (obvious) side effects that could affect the preview mechanism?!?

Comment: @PerLindgren Previews are always kind of glitchy. Sometimes previews don't match how the app looks in the simulator at all. Just use the simulator instead.

Comment: Yep, I spoke too soon. All previews in all projects behaved the same. I tried a few things (relaying, rebuilding) without effect. Then I rebooted, and at the same time upgraded to MacOS 14.4. Now it works! But I don't know if it's because of the reboot, the upgrade - or the combination...